# JSF 2.0 @managedproperty not working from one viewScoped bean to another view scoped bean

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, managed-bean, view-scope

I have a **@viewScoped** bean( say **bean1)** having an inputText as property .From the facelet, Iam setting the value of this inputtext field. However after the submit operation when the other facelet (whose managed bean say **bean2** is in **@viewScoped** ) as well is loaded ,I need to retrieve the bean1 inputText values but iam not able to retrieve .I know in viewscoped bean the state is lost once we move to next view but  is there a way to retrieve the values ? because i need to show the values in the next facelet ... By the way Iam using ajax so the bean has to be viewscoped

I even tried  the following code in bean2 (@viewScoped) .but the sysout shown below is always null

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{bean1}")
private Bean1 bean1;

System.out.println(bean1.getinputtext());
```

both the beans have to be in @viewScoped .Is there a way I can retrieve the values from bean 1 to bean 2 ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access first view scoped bean any more. You can add your data to session, read that data from second bean and remove the data.

Comment: Yes .There is no way we can access without using session . this link also helped me . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480325/how-to-save-an-object-into-jsf-session .thanks @partlov